# Symfony2: Get the validator constraints of a field in a field theme

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to get the validator constraint messages from an entity to show underneath form input fields (before / without there being an error on the form POST). What's the best way to do this? I've tried multiple things but can't get anything to work. Any help?

Comment: Have you read the Docs regarding the [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) Form Component ?
You have full control over where the errors get displayed for a field:
    <div>
        {{ form_label(form.task) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.task) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.task) }}
    </div>

Your question is not very well formatted. Like this, without any code example of what you are trying to do, is a bit difficult to write any help.